# C# Regular Expression search this value

Tags: c#

How get the number this string text?

string stringvalue = "[3=000][98=000][299=000][120=000][012=000][92=000][93=000][04=000]";

```
        string pattern = "([)([0-2][0-9][0-9])(=)";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(stringvalue);
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=== Sonuç ===");
            foreach (Match match in matches)
                Console.WriteLine("value={0}", match.Value.Replace("[", "").Replace("=", ""));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bulunamdı");
        }
```

Is anaother vay string pattern = "([)([0-2][0-9][0-9])(=)"; this is pattern(No replace)

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand this correctly. In what kind of data / collection type do you store these integer numbers? Is it a `int[]`, or a `List<string>`, or something else? And is your goal to transform that list into a string like the last line? What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

`\[(\d+)=\d+\]`

The numbers you are looking for will be in the first group of each Match:

```
var input = "[03=000][98=000][999=000][120=000][01=000][92=000][93=000][1004=000]";
var regex = @"\[(\d+)=\d+\]";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, regex);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Markus I neeed 

03
98
999
120
01
92
93
1004
only values...

Comment: I try regular expression above my code and no replace.

Comment: What exaclty is your problem? The above code gives you exactly these values.

Comment: I don't use replace method only pattern gives values.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes found regular expressions a little bit nasty. You can just consider using naive string processing instead of matching regular expression. This will certainly do the job for your input.

```
string val  = "[03=000][98=000][999=000][120=000][01=000][92=000][93=000][1004=000]";

string[] numbers = val.Split(new []{ '[', ']', '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 0)
                      .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers));
```

prints:

```
03
98
999
120
01
92
93
1004
```

Comment: I try regular expression above my code and no replace.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you right, you are saying the bottom is all one string? If so, no need for Regex (though you could use it), but I would just use substrings since you seem to want them separate.

i.e. string str03 = ThatString.Substring(1,2);

str03 would equal "03"

Comment: How will you find all occurances using that approach? Also, the numbers differ in length.

Comment: The first argument in Substring() is the index in the string where you want to start capturing, and the second is where you want to end. So you just need to toggle those.

Comment: Toggle based on what?

Comment: What numbers you need. For example, suppose you have this string : test = "abcdefg" and you needed "efg" you would just go : string fg = test.Substring(5,7);

Comment: I won't ask how you get **all** numbers OP asks, and give directly a `-1`

Comment: And I wont ask you how you wouldn't understand to do so after one simple example, and give you a high five to kill you with kindness :)